# How to access my /home partition?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I am very new to Linux. I installed Ubuntu, tried to add a `/home` partition, messed up, formatted again, etc. Then finally I added `/home` by selecting "Something Else".

Now I can see that I have a `/home` in `gparted` but I can't see anything in File System GUI! Below is a screen shot of my `gparted`

[image]

Below is a screen shot from my file system

[image]

How can I access this `/home` partition? All I can see is a `home` folder in `Computer`

Comment: Double click on the `/home` folder, there you will find your personal folder. The mounted partition is visible as a folder.

Comment: everything is a file

Comment: " How can I access this "/home" partition?"  Linux does not show you partitions in the file browser and puts it ALL together as 1 big area of files and directories where /home/ IS a partition but also a directory and you see this directory in your image. We do not have a D: where you need to go to a different disk.

Comment: @mchid nope. Everything is a file **descriptor** ( anonymous pipes and network sockets are not files  ;-) )

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I have no `/home` folder. I have a "home" folder.

Comment: Sure, You have :) "/" means: looking at it from the root directory, which is `/`, the trunk of all sub-directories.  The actual *name* of the folder is `home`, but its *path* is `/home` (again, walking to the `home` folder, starting from the root directory).

Comment: @JacobVlijm: wow, Linux is showing partitions as folders then.. In windows I could see them separately.

Comment: You can, simply by running in a terminal `lsblk`, but it is another way of thinking indeed.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I right clicked on my "home" folder and clicked on properties. The size is 276.3 GB which proves it is a partition. But it is slightly larger than the allocated space of the partition. How can this happen?

Comment: ...Have to run, I will get back if I get home again, if still necessary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first screenshot, there is a KEY next to the blue square in the third line.  That means that the partition is mounted, so theoretically, you ought to be able to access it, and I think you ARE accessing it without realizing it.

By giving it the mount point of `/home`, one of the "homes" of your directory system is that entire partition.  I'm guessing it is the higher one and I'm going to enumerate the steps to determine if I am correct.

1. Navigate your file manager so that your screen looks just as it is in your second screenshot.
2. Click on the back arrow in the upper left corner.
3. You *should* see a screen with probably only two folders in it, and one of them should be named for your account name, "Yohan" apparently.
4. Right click on "Yohan" and select properties.  If I'm correct the free space on that folder should be over 200 gb, proving that the folder is in fact the partition you seek.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I open the file manager, what get opened is "home" which is under "places" category of file manager. So if I access "Computer" clicking the back arrow will take me back to "Home" section.

Comment: I see.  I'm comparing that to my file manager.  As I'm using version 12.04LTS, it would appear to be slightly different.  I do have a devices menu but no option called "computer".  It sounds familiar though and as I've used many generations of Ubuntu including 14, which appears to be what you are using, and even 15.04 beta, it seems likely I have seen that generation of file manager.

Comment: But wait. The "home" folder in "/" is larger than 200GB. It is 276.3 GB, actually larger than the partition!

Comment: In that case it may be that your installation is actually on the larger "/home" partition and that the root partition is busy doing something else.  Not sure what.  Obviously, its not busy being the root directory.  For a new user, you sure find strange things to do with Ubuntu.  May I recommend you try a default installation and have fun in other ways such as becoming hand with using it to scan windows drives for viruses, recovering data for the owners of those drives and maybe even learning to use WINE.  You do that and your Windows friends let you install Ubuntu!

Comment: actually it is slightly large, the partition is 275.67 and the folder shows 276.3

Comment: It is normal for the reported size to appear larger than the figure seen in the partitioning tool.  It's not an error in the partitioning tool but something to do with the cluster sizes and precise math.  Please don't quote me but I think it may have something also to do with the fact that a kilobyte is not 1000 but 1024, so you have more byte than you think.  When I got into computer repair in the late 1980's I made it a point not to worry about such matters but simply accept them.  I leave the piddly bits to the computer scientists.

Comment: ` I leave the piddly bits to the computer scientists.` - Then it comes to us, to the poor researchers :(

Comment: I would like to make an observation regarding that first partition.  Please note that gparted refers to how used space there is.  This means that some portion of Ubuntu was installed there six and a half gb apparently there, with an additional four and a half in the /home directory.  I'm still trying to understand how you managed a 10gb installation unless this installation isn't very recent, but I digress.

Comment: Installation is brand new. I made partitions while installing. why?

Comment: 10 gb just seems like a lot.  I make full ubuntu installations complete with additions like GIMP, WINE, SKYPE, OPERA, some custom wallpapers, and a host of other programs, and even a windows utility in the download folder, and I barely occupy 6gb.  If you got 10gb, either Ubuntu 14 is massively more bloated than 12, or you did something to fill all that space.

Comment: hmm.. No idea on thaty.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the folder that is called "home" and then click on your username folder; the partition should be mounted and available here.

Open a terminal and type the following command to confirm this:

```
lsblk
```

You should see the partition listed here and it should have a mountpoint listed as well. If no mount point is listed, you need to edit `/etc/fstab` to include the partition to be mounted when you boot at `/home/<your_username>`.

Comment: actually, i see it's already listed as mounted at /home in your screenshot

Comment: how can I access "/home" ? In terminal if I type `cd /home` am I accessing the partition or home folder?

Comment: @JustCause They are one in the same kind of because the /home folder is where the partition is. All the contents of /home are stored on the home partition so all the contents of the partition are in /home. "/home" is the "mount point" of that partition (that is where the partition is mounted at). Your main partition is mounted at "/" .

Comment: OK, So linux is showing partitions as folders.... In windows I can see them separately. Hope I don't have to re-install everything..

Comment: reinstall? what for? in windows, your main partition is c: and another partition would be d: right? so in ubuntu and linux what would have been "c:\" is now  "/" and "d:\" is now "/home/"

Comment: Thanks. I right clicked on my "home" folder and clicked on properties. The size is 276.3 GB which proves it is a partition. But it is slightly larger than the allocated space of the partition. How can this happen?

Comment: Regarding your size discrepancy, you're most likely looking at a [GB vs. GiB](http://wintelguy.com/gb2gib.html) issue.